# I have error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKQEv.png)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int cout=100;
    int *m=&cout;
    cout<<"dia chi cua bien cout"<<&cout<<endl;
    cout<<"gia tri cua bien cout"<<cout<<endl;
    cout<<"dia chi cua bien m"<<&m<<endl;
    cout<<"gia tri cua bien m"<<m<<endl;
    return 0;

    
}
```

please help me where is wrong cause i have a hard time with this.

Comment: Don't name a variable the same as something else that already exists. You named your variable `cout` but at the same time you want `cout` to be the `cout` from the standard library. How is the compiler supposed to know which one you mean when you write `cout`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've named your `int` variable to `cout` and then treating it as if it was the `cout` from the standard library.

To solve this, you can rename the `int` variable to be something different from `cout`.

Also, avoid using `using namespace std;` wherever possible. Using `std::cout` is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).